# Remote push notifications in SwiftUI App Life Cycle not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, apple-push-notifications

The request for notification permission pop up will appear and then I'll press allow and all that, but none of the delegate functions (didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError or didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken work, and I'm testing on a real device...). I've enabled push notifications in Signing & Capabilities and have registered through Apple Developer for the cert and saved it to my keychain. Any help would be appreciated!

```
@main
struct Sparrow_NavigationApp: App {
    
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            RootView {
                ContentView()
            }
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
          .requestAuthorization(
            options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, _ in
            print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
            guard granted else { return }
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in
                print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
                guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
              }
          }
        return true
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        guard let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: AnyObject] else {
            completionHandler(.failed)
            return
          }
        print("got something, aka the \(aps)")
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("device token")
        let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data in String(format: "%02.2hhx", data) }
        let token = tokenParts.joined()
        print("Device Token: \(token)")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Device Token not found.")
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkfDh.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dABWZ.png

Comment: Seems like you are doing everything correct, so the problem could be somewhere with the connection with APNs:
1. Try to use cellular instead of wife, put the device in Airplane mode for a while or reboot it
2. Double check that you provision profile is valid and include Push Notifications option is turned ON and under Background Modes, Remote Notifications is turned ON

Comment: Note that registering for remote notifications is independent to having permission to display notifications.  You can register for remote notifications outside of the permission request code

Comment: Your code works for me; I added it to a test app, ran it and once I granted notification permissions the device token was printed.

On subsequent runs, the device token was also printed, since notifications had previously been allowed.
I went into settings for the app and turned off notification permissions and the token was no longer printed.  After I re-enabled notification permission the token was displayed.

Comment: @Paulw11 Hi Paul, sorry on the EXTREMELY late replies--I added two pictures for clarification that I've set up the provisioning profile and background modes correctly. No idea why this isn't working...I've tried the device suggestions suggested by ATV. What else could it be?

Comment: @ATV Hi, sorry for the extremely late reply--I've tried your suggestions, but nothing has worked. I added two pictures for clarification that I'm setting up the provisioning profiles correctly. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you set breakpoints and stepped through to confirm the path your code is taking?  Have you deleted the app from your device and installed it again?

Comment: @Paulw11 Well I'm sure it's going through the whole didFinishLaunchingApplication function in the way I want (getting to the dispatch queue), but it's never hitting the didRegisterForRemoteNotifs, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotifs, and didReceiveRemoteNotifs, we could maybe hop on a discord call and I could screen share?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but you are running on a real device, and not on the simulator?

Comment: Yep, running it on my phone. Tried restarting, uninstalling, going into airplane mode for a bit, then into cellular, just cellular, wifi, just wifi--nothing worked :/ and it's definitely something dumb that I'm missing too @Paulw11

Comment: @nickcoding2, did you ever figure this out? I'm having this exact issue. registerForRemoteNotifications() is printing what appears to be a successful deviceToken, but the delegate func is not being called afterwards.

Comment: @Jarem not all the same delegate methods get called in the adapter